# Is there a true false method to see which current SKView is presented?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob

I am trying to present a reward to users after they watch a video. I'm not sure if I can have two different rewardBasedVideoAds functions. So, I need both scenes to direct to this rewardbasedvideoad function and then send the user back to their respective scene once the ad is complete. Is there any way to do this with the SKScene view? Am I doing it wrong? I would appreciate feedback. Thank you!

```
 func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if view.self == GameScene.self {
            continueBasic = continueBasic + 1
            let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
        if view == self.view as? ClassicScene{
            continueRGB = continueRGB + 1
            let scene = ClassicScene(size: view.bounds.size)
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I should have just given a variable the ability to change with the scenes so that if a current scene is displayed I can change the variable by writing something like:

```
currentScene = "GameScene"
```

Either way, here is the finished product. Hope it helps someone!

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if currentScene == "GameScene" {
            continueBasic = continueBasic + 1
            let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
            view.presentScene(scene)
        } else if currentScene == "ClassicScene"{
            continueRGB = continueRGB + 1
            let scene = ClassicScene(size: view.bounds.size)
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
```